# Domains tab missing in geodatabase properties?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, domains, fields-attributes

I'm fairly new to ArcGIS Desktop. I started working on a feature layer in a new geodatabase yesterday, adding attribute fields and creating coded domains for them.

However today when I opened it up again, the Domains tab is missing. ie. it doesn't show up in Catalog --> mygdb.gdb -> [right click] -> Properties. Yesterday there were only 2 tabs in Properties - General & Domains. Today there's General, Sharing, Security, Previous Versions, Customize. But no Domains.

Any idea why this is or how to get it back?

I know I can go into Domains from the Data Management toolbox to create them but it's quicker and much more convenient to do it from the gdb's Properties.

Answer (score 1):

When viewing properties on a file geodatabase from Windows Explorer, you will not be presented with any ArcMap or ArcCatalog properties.  You will see General, Sharing, Security, Previous Versions, and Customize tabs when right-clicking on a folder in Windows Explorer; Windows Explorer will typically show your geodatabase with a folder icon, not a geodatabase icon like in ArcGIS Desktop.

If you go into ArcCatalog or use the Catalog Window within ArcMap, you will be able to right-click on your geodatabase and get the properties you are looking for there.